# Error while adding a custom html to Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm not really into JS, could you tell me what's wrong with this code? I tried to add this but an error occurs "Error at line 74, character 3: Parse error. ')' expected". I don't really know what to repair.

```
<script id="gtm-scroll-tracking" type="text/javascript">
    ; (function (document, window, config) {
        // Browser dependencies, script fails silently
        if (!document.querySelector || !document.body.getBoundingClientRect) {
            return false;
        }
        // Get our dataLayer ready, in case we're not in GTM or we've got a special name
        var dataLayerName = config.dataLayerName || 'dataLayer';
        var dataLayer = window[dataLayerName] || (window[dataLayerName] = []);
        var cache = {};
        // Initialize our distances, for later
        config.distances = config.distances || {};
        checkDepth();
        addEvent(window, 'scroll', throttle(checkDepth, 500));
        function getMarks(_docHeight, _offset) {
            var marks = {};
            var percents = [];
            var pixels = []
            if (config.distances.percentages) {
                if (config.distances.percentages.each) {
                    percents = percents.concat(config.distances.percentages.each);
                }
                if (config.distances.percentages.every) {
                    var _every = every_(config.distances.percentages.every, 100);
                    percents = percents.concat(_every);
                }
            }
            if (config.distances.pixels) {
                if (config.distances.pixels.each) {
                    pixels = pixels.concat(config.distances.pixels.each);
                }
                if (config.distances.pixels.every) {
                    var _every = every_(config.distances.pixels.every, _docHeight);
                    pixels = pixels.concat(_every);
                }
            }
            marks = addMarks_(marks, percents, '%', _docHeight, _offset);
            marks = addMarks_(marks, pixels, 'px', _docHeight, _offset);
            return marks;
        }
        function addMarks_(marks, points, symbol, _docHeight, _offset) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                var _point = parseInt(points[i], 10);
                var height = symbol !== '%' ? _point + _offset : _docHeight *
                    (_point / 100) + _offset;
                var mark = _point + symbol;
                if (height <= _docHeight + _offset) { marks[mark] = height; }
            }
            return marks;
        }
        function every_(n, total) {
            var n = parseInt(n, 10);
            var _num = total / n;
            var arr = [];
            for (i = 1; i < _num + 1; i++) { arr.push(i * n); }
            return arr;
        }
        function checkDepth() {
            var _bottom = parseBorder_(config.bottom);
            var _top = parseBorder_(config.top);
            var height = docHeight(_bottom, _top);
            var marks = getMarks(height, (_top || 0));
            var _curr = currentPosition();
            for (key in marks) {
                if (_curr > marks[key] && !cache[key]) {
                    cache[key] = true;
                    fireAnalyticsEvent(key);
                }
            }
        }
        function fireAnalyticsEvent(distance) {
            dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'scrollTracking',
                'attributes': { 'distance': distance }
            });
        }
    }
    function parseBorder_(border) {
        if (typeof border === 'Number' || parseInt(border, 10)) {
            return parseInt(border, 10);
        }
        try {
            // If we have an element or a query selector, poll getBoundingClientRect
            var el = border.nodeType && border.nodeType === 1 ? border :
                document.querySelector(border);
            var docTop = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            var _elTop = Math.floor(el.getBoundingClientRect().top - docTop);
            return _elTop;
        } catch (e) { return void (0); }
    }
    // Adapted from
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY
    function currentPosition() {
        var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
        var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");
        var currScrollTop = supportPageOffset ?
            window.pageYOffset :
            isCSS1Compat ?
                document.documentElement.scrollTop :
                document.body.scrollTop;
        return parseInt(currScrollTop, 10) + parseInt(viewportHeight(), 10);
    }
    function viewportHeight() {
        var elem = (document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat") ?
            document.documentElement :
            document.body;
        return elem.clientHeight;
    }
    function docHeight(_bottom, _top) {
        var body = document.body;
        var html = document.documentElement;
        var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
            html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
        if (_top) { height = height - _top; }
        if (_bottom) { height = _bottom - _top; }
        return height - 5;
    }
    /*
     * Throttle function borrowed from:
     * Underscore.js 1.5.2
     * http://underscorejs.org
     *
  (c) 2009-2013 Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud and Investigative
  Reporters & Editors
     * Underscore may be freely distributed under the MIT license.
     */
    function throttle(func, wait) {
        var context, args, result;
        var timeout = null;
        var previous = 0;
        var later = function () {
            previous = new Date;
            timeout = null;
            result = func.apply(context, args);
        };
        return function () {
            var now = new Date;
            if (!previous) previous = now;
            var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
            context = this;
            args = arguments;
            if (remaining <= 0) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = null;
                previous = now;
                result = func.apply(context, args);
            } else if (!timeout) {
                timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
            }
            return result;
        };
    }
    // Cross-browser compliant event listener
    function addEvent(el, evt, fn) {
        if (el.addEventListener) { return el.addEventListener(evt, fn); }
        if (el.attachEvent) {
            return el.attachEvent('on' + evt, function (evt) {
                // Call the event to ensure uniform 'this' handling, pass it event
                fn.call(el, evt);
            });
        }
        if (typeof el['on' + evt] === 'undefined' || el['on' + evt] === null) {
            return el['on' + evt] = function (evt) {
                // Call the event to ensure uniform 'this' handling, pass it event
                fn.call(el, evt); \
            }
        }
    }
    })(document, window,
        {
            // False if you just use the default dataLayer variable, otherwise enter it here
            'dataLayerName': false,
            'distances': {
                // Configure percentages of page you'd like to see if users scroll past
                'percentages': {
                    'each': [10, 90],
                    'every': 25
                },
                // Configure for pixel measurements of page you'd like to see if users scroll past
                'pixels': {
                    'each': [],
                    'every': null
                }
            },
            // Accepts a number, DOM element, or query selector to determine the top of the scrolling area
            'top': null,
            // Accepts a number, DOM element, or query selector to determine the bottom of the scrolling area
            'bottom': null,
        });
</script>
```

While trying to preview (debug), the tool tells me:

> Error at line 74, character 3: Parse error. ')' expected

Comment: This is an issue with the code/JavaScript you have copy pasted in the Custom HTML Tag, basically the code is not closing of a function correctly. The provided snippet in your post makes this hard to debug as there are numerous issues with it e.g. The Comments towards the end are not on the same line as the //,, possible due to the formatting when pasted in the post.

Does your website use jQuery? If so you can try to implement this script, it provides instructions for Google Tag Manager as well. http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/. This will also track the scroll depth.

Comment: First off, do some of your own debugging and narrow down your code. There's way too much for anyone to want to go through.